How to specify the MIME type for a custom preload link
I need to preload a text file with a custom extension on a HTML page. I tried this:
<link rel="preload" href="myfile.xxx" as="fetch" type="text/plain">

But it is being preloaded with a "octet-stream" media type. Is it possible to override that (without changing anything on the server side)?

I don't fully understand. If the server set content-type:text/plain when sending the file, it should be preloaded as text/plain even if its extension is .exe as far as I know.

@SyndRain I think the problem is exactly that .. The content-type is wrong, and OP is trying to manipulate that with plain HTML.  Which, of course, is impossible.

According to Moz Developer .. What you are doing won't work.
It associates using a MIME type of text/plain with the acutal file extension of .txt.
There is no way to reliably do this in straight HTML.  What you probably need to do, is write an .htaccess rule that will serve your file type up as a .txt file instead of your custom extension. IE
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).xxx$ https://example.com/$1.txt [R=301,L]

The other option is to simply rename those files to .txt.  If you are serving them as text/plain --  You should  be serving the files with the correct extension if you want <link> to work and the correct type to be detected.
OR use a server-side method of serving the content-type as text/plain for extension xxx
